# Accessing custom JavaScript functions via RPC API on Geth

Tags: json-rpc, javascript, rpc

Geth allows me to define & load my own custom JavaScript functions with `--preload` flag or `require()` on Geth console.

But is there way to access my functions via RPC interface?

Like :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"mycustom_function()","params":[],"id":123}'
```

I've seen i can open access to more management APIs with `--rpcapi eth,web3,admin,eth,miner` but it doesnt work for my custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

`--preload` is an easy way to add commonly used functions and objects to geth console. You cannot access them using RPC interface.

For example, if you are interacting with a contract deployed at address `addr` with ABI `abi`, you can create a file with `MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(0x1)` and preload it using `--preload`. So you can simply access your contract method using `MyContract` object inside geth console.